# Can you make 3d product models in SilverLight 3?

Tags: silverlight, 3d, viewport

I've been using ViewPoint to make 3d models for some time, but I'm intrigued with the prospect of moving those models to Silverlight. I have pretty good asp.net experience but have never created a Silverlight App. Are there any good tutorials out there on creating 3d models in Silverlight 3 beta?

Answer (score 2):

See Reed's answer - [Kit3D](http://kit3d.codeplex.com/) is your best bet (whether Silverlight 2.0 *or* 3.0) - check out [some](http://sildev.net/3DCubes/index.html) [examples](http://www.markdawson.org/Kit3D/).

If you've read about the new *'3D capabilities of Silverlight 3.0'*, it is not actually a complete 3D system (a-la WPF) but rather a new type of Transform that (basically) "renders a flat surface in 3D space".

It's called **PlaneProjection** and lets you do stuff like [this](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/04/silverlight-30-planeprojection.html) and [this](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/05/silverlight-maps-that-bend-upwards.html). It is great for flipping stuff around (like a carousel control) and similar effects (also implementing Photosynth where the deepzoomimages need to be positioned in '3D'), but NOT really capable of rendering a 3D model as such.

If you decide to play with Kit3D (or WPF's 3D stuff) the [Charles Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/3D/) book really helped me understand the basics of it all...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, even in Silverlight 2, using the [Kit3D engine](http://kit3d.codeplex.com/) for Silverlight.

This library provides Silverlight with a 3D engine very similar to WPF's Media3D tools.